# concat 2 dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

i have 2 dataframe I have to concatenate them by checking two conditions

they must have the same id and id1

first dataframe

```
index     id     id1    name       sexe      age
0         30     AA     momo        M         21
1         31     AA     soso        M         25
2         32     AA     momo        M         18
3         30     BB     LOLO        M         20
4         31     BB     toto        F         20
```

second dataframe

```
index     id     id1    note      
0         30     AA      18
1         31     AA      20
2         32     AA      11
3         30     BB       0
4         31    BB       0
```

Ihave to check if they have the same id1 and id

final dataframe

```
index     id     id1    name       sexe      age      note
0         30     AA     momo        M         21       18
1         31     AA     soso        M         25       20 
2         32     AA     momo        M         18       11
3         30     BB     LOLO        M         20        0
4         31     BB     toto        F         20        0
```

id is not unique
how can i do that ,i find a duplication problem if i convert id1 to index

Comment: `pd.merge(df1.set_index('index'), df2.set_index('index'), on=['id', 'id1'], how='left').fillna(0)`?

Comment: the column label 'id' is not unique.